# microsoft jscript runtime error object doesn't support this property or method jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I a using asp.net vs 2008.I am trying jquery. I am getting this error 
**"microsoft jscript runtime error object doesn't support this property or method jquery"**
Any help is appreciated.

This is the code i am using.

```
 <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            ("button").click(function() {
                $("p").hide();
            });
        });  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a $ i think

```
        $("button").click(function() {
            $("p").hide();
        });
```